# Trying to Scanner from delimited txt file into a String Array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a tab delimited txt file and put the data into two columns of a String array.

```
package mailsender;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MailSenderList {
    static String address=null;
    static String name=null;
    static String[][] mailer;

   // @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/fotis/Documents/MailRecipients.txt"),'\t')); //This is the path and the name of my file

            for(int i=0;i>=30;i++){
               for(int j=0;j>=2;j++){
                   if (s.hasNext());{
                   mailer[i][j]=s.next(); //here i am trying to put 1st+2 word into first column and 2nd+2 into second column.
               }

               }
           }
            for(int ii=0;ii>=30;ii++){
                System.out.println("Line : ");
               for(int ji=0;ji>=2;ji++){
                   System.out.print(" " + mailer[ii][ji]);
//trying to print and check the array
               }
           }

        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file, ending program");
        //System.exit(1);}


    }
}
class mail{
mail(){

}

}
}
```

The file builds successfully but no result in `System.out.In` debugger, it seems as it never passes from the first `for` loop.

Comment: The code will never enter either for loop. You are saying i=0, and while i is greater than or equal to 30, which it is not, so it will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed.For was so wrong.But I was dizzy.
Nevertheless , confusing "<>" was not the real problem.
The code worked with while.
Here is the whole class.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File file = new File("/home/fotis/Documents/Mailers.txt"); //this a the path there
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\t")) {
                String line[] = new String[150000];
                int i=0;


                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    line[i] = input.next();
                    System.out.println(line[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Well, yes this works better. But your originally problem was that you mixed up greater than and less than.

Answer (score 1):

You probably made a mistake between < and >. Try switching i >= 30 in both for loops to i <= 30. Same with the j loops.